# Parametrized data class with variance

Tags: kotlin, generics

I have such class

```
data class MyClass<T, out R>(
    val data: T? = null,
    val error: R? = null
)
```

But actually I want my `error` to extend `Throwable`, for example.
How should I declare MyClass for this purpose?

Comment: Do you mean: `MyClass<T, out R : Throwable>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `Throwable` constraint to `R` (see [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html#generic-constraints)):

```kotlin
data class MyClass<T, out R : Throwable>(
    val data: T? = null,
    val error: R? = null
)
```